# How do I make it when the program finished executing and add an option if the user want to try again it executes the program again

Tags: c

I got this school project in which we'll have to code a some sort of a calculator using Dev C++ and it has to have an option in which the user chooses weather to try and calculate again with a different inputs or another key to exit the program.

My problem is, on the option to try again or exit the program, when i input the option to execute again it just automatically executes everything and doesn't give the option to input characters or anything.

Here is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int main(){

int a,b,choice;
using namespace std;
system("cls");  
printf("\t===============================================================\n"
);
printf("\n\t\t\t\tFinals Project I\n\n");
printf("\t\t\t   Program Status : Complete\n\n");
printf("\t===============================================================\n\
n");
printf("Loading libraries...");
sleep(3);
printf("\tSuccess\n");
printf("Binding program libs...");
sleep(2);
printf("\tSuccess\n");
printf("Executing program...");
sleep(2);
printf("\tSuccess\n\n");
printf("Program Started!\n\n"); 

do{ 
printf("Please select valid operation (+ - / *):\t");
char operation;
scanf("%c", &operation);

    switch(operation){
        case '+': 
            printf("\nEnter 1st number:\t");
            scanf("%d",&a);
            printf("\nEnter 2nd number:\t");
            scanf("%d",&b);
            printf("\nAnswer is %d",a+b);
            break;
        case '-':
            printf("Enter 1st number:\n");
            scanf("%d",&a);
            printf("Enter 2nd number:\n");
            scanf("%d",&b);
            printf("Answer is %d",a-b);
            break;
        case '/':
            printf("Enter 1st number:\n");
            scanf("%d",&a);
            printf("Enter 2nd number:\n");
            scanf("%d",&b);
            printf("Answer is %d",a/b);
            break;
        case '*':
            printf("Enter 1st number:\n");
            scanf("%d",&a);
            printf("Enter 2nd number:\n");
            scanf("%d",&b);
            printf("Answer is %d",a*b);
            break;
        default : printf("Incorrect! Operation not Valid...\n"); break;
    }
    printf("\nDo you want to try again? :\n[1] YES\n[0] NO\t :\t>>");
    scanf("%d",&choice);
}while(choice!=0);

printf("\n\nExiting Program...[Press any Key]");
getch();
}

/*

((operation=='+')||(operation=='-')||(operation=='/')||(operation=='*'))


*/
```

Comment: the same as how you take the `operation`

Comment: and this is not a `c++` Q, I'd remove the tag.

Comment: Whenever you need to repeat something, loops is a natural solution.

Comment: And before your next question (and I'm sure one's coming), please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And of course please learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Lastly please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest) In short the answer is: Never.

Comment: Unrelated, but what nonsense is this please: `printf("Loading libraries...");
sleep(3);
printf("\tSuccess\n");
printf("Binding program libs...");
sleep(2);
printf("\tSuccess\n");
printf("Executing program...");
sleep(2);` ??

Comment: Once the program has terminated, it is gone. You should implement a loop _within_ the program.

Comment: Debug 101: check the value returned by scanf, printf out the value read by every scanf, (if char, printf the ASCII value).  Your main() should be only a short 'Again?' loop that calls a function to run the core of your app.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie or *outside* the program, which fits the title better :)

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. Turns out I had to put "Space" before the "%c" on first scanf syntax. Thanks everyone for your comments and I'm sorry I was not specific with the code example. I copy and pasted everything.